Relationship between inrush current, blowing the fuse and switching power supplies with PFC
I'm having the problem that my (switching) power supply of my new "mobile workstation" (laptop) is blowing the 230V/16A (about 40 years old) fuse (circuit breaker) most of the time when plugging in the power supply to the wall socket.
The power supply is rated 230W (so so).
However there are basically no other consumers on that fuse at that time.
I also had a similar problem on another circuit with a BeQuiet 450W power supply, while I did not have one with an Enermax 750W power supply that was older.
The solution for that time was to replace the circuit breaker with a 14A model that would not trigger that fast.
Not wanting to replace all the circuit breakers in the house (it has to be done by an electrician in Germany (=expensive)), I'm considering to add an inrush current limiter instead.
However I try to understand why seemingly lower-rated power supplies "blow the fuse", while stronger ones did not:
Is it because the electronics become cheaper, and "soft start" isn't implemented any more, or is it due to "PFC" (Power Factor Conversion) as Einschaltstrombegrenzung und Softstart bei Netzteilen (German) suggests ("Schaltnetzteile mit aktiver elektronischer Leistungsfaktorkorrektur (PFC) haben ebenfalls das Problem eines hohen Einschaltstroms" ("Switch-mode power supplies with active electronic power factor correction (PFC) also have the problem of a high inrush current"))?
So basically:
What are the reasons for the problem, and what are possible solutions?
Details
Here is an image of the circuit breaker (left left one is the one in question; the right one is a replacement from last year that does not have that problem.

And here's a photo of the power supply's data with a lot of certifications (sorry for the reflection):


What's the fuse characteristic, A, B, C or D?

What does "fuse (circuit breaker)" mean?  Is it a fuse or a circuit breaker?

Is it a RCD type breaker?

I'm afraid, the thing is to old to have an A-D characteristic. Be patient, I'll add a photo when I'm back home. In German i't basically the same word ("Sicherung") for both types, but to be more precise one would use "Schmelzsicherung" ("melting fuse") or "Sicherungsautomat" (~"automatic fuse"). So it's the second type.

As @TimWilliams is hinting at, if it's an RCD breaker, your problem may be leakage current to ground rather than inrush.  In that case, limiting inrush current won't solve the problem.  It would be unusual for inrush on such a small supply to blow a 16 A 230 V breaker.  On the other hand, breakers do age and can false trip so a new breaker might be necessary.

Same language issue in Swedish. Still, leakage current is probably the issue here but with an A or possibly B type fuse and shorted NTC inrush, you could trip it. I doubt it with a regular C, as your other fuse is.

Interestingly, using the same type of circuit breaker, but connecting the power supply in the cellar does not blow the fuse; my guess is that the longer wires have enough resistance to limit the inrush current.

Try using a power strip with RFI suppression (radio frequency interference filter) with that power supply. There are inductors in such a device to reduce sudden inrush current, and capacitors to reduce voltage spikes, both of which might be triggering the circuit breaker.

The small loads you mention should not be tripping breakers. If they do, they are old and weak, or there may be a GFCI issue. When the brakes on your car get weak and fade. Do you open the door and use your feet to stop the vehicle like Fred Flinstone or get the brakes fixed?
This thread needs to be closed. The OP is asking how to circumvent the required safety device.

@Dereck I'm not really on "circumventing the required safety device"; instead I'm trying to understand the obvious paradoxon that lower-rated power supplies using PFC seem to trigger a fuse while higher rated power supplies seem not to do so. Or in a nutshell: Does PFC cause a higher inrush current (as the Wikipedia article seems to say), or is it unrelated? I'm sorry if the question wasn't clear enough.
